# Replace the value in xml using Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am using [xml_edit](https://github.com/martinb3-cookbooks/xmledit-cookbook/issues/18) to change the value of xml. This is not working with below scenario.

I want to change the title of **Atwood, Margaret** author in **Second Bookshelf** in below xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookshelf>
   <Name>First Bookshelf</Name>
   <book>
      <author>Conway, Damien</author>
      <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Atwood, Margaret</author>
      <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
   </book>
</bookshelf>
<bookshelf>
   <Name>Second Bookshelf</Name>
   <book>
      <author>Conway, Damien</author>
      <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Atwood, Margaret</author>
      <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
   </book>
</bookshelf>
```

I am trying to use below recipe. I do't know, how could I verify the **Name and auther** of second bookshelf.

```
xml_edit 'change title' do
    path 'C:\\testing\\text.xml'
    target '/bookshelf/book/title[text()=\'Perl Best Practices\']'
    fragment '<title>Hello World</title>'
    action :replace

end
```

Comment: Please provide more details like how do you define target, how your recipe look like and logs.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your xml is not valid
It should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<shelves>
<bookshelf>
    <Name>First Bookshelf</Name>
    <book>
        <author>Conway, Damien</author>
        <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Atwood, Margaret</author>
        <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
    </book>
</bookshelf>
<bookshelf>
    <Name>Second Bookshelf</Name>
    <book>
        <author>Conway, Damien</author>
        <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Atwood, Margaret</author>
        <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
    </book>
</bookshelf>
</shelves>
```

With that in mind you can do:

```
xml_edit 'change title' do
    path 'C:\\testing\\text.xml'
    target '/shelves/bookshelf[Name[text()=\'Second Bookshelf\']]/book[author[text()=\'Atwood, Margaret\']]/title'
    fragment '<title>Hello World</title>'
    action :replace
end
```